# Swap with preview 'Complete Swap' step restarts production slot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have Web App with two slots for ASP.NET MVC application. Slots have equal settings. I deploy to "preproduction" slot to check couple of things and warm up application itself. I don't quite understand what 'Start swap' does, because app does not look to be restarted and it is still warmed up. When I click 'Complete swap' I expect it to swap application instances with production slot, so users won't notice the change, or it would be at least less than of 20 seconds of production down. What I have instead is: production slot is down for 2 minutes after swap is completed and I have to warm up it again.

On the other hand, other developers from my team say that on the other projects 'Swap with preview' feature is perfect for application warmup, so I guess it is not expected behaviour.

What is even more strange... Is that I feel that **sometimes** it does what I expect from it. And swap goes almost immediately and my app stays warmed up.

Could anyone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this is actually wait some time after step 1 (Start swap) is completed. Don't complete swap immediately. Looks like 'preproduction' slot gets restarted around minute after, so if you swap too fast, then it is reloaded when it is already a production.

So after a minute or so you can warm up your app again and then complete swap (step 2). Swap goes smoothly and immediately in this case.